# android fragment button in include tag does not work

Tags: android, xml, button, include, fragment

I have faced a problem, that my button does not work when I use

Here is my fragment_category_sub xml file:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

      ...

    <include
        layout="@layout/content_unavailable"
        />

    ....
```

And here is my include xml file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/content_unavailable"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:gravity="center"
android:padding="16dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/try_again"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/error_default_tryAgain"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my fragment were I try to implement setOnClickListener:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category_sub, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, rootView);

    contentUnavailable = rootView.findViewById(R.id.content_unavailable);

    Button buttonAgain = (Button) 
    contentUnavailable.findViewById(R.id.try_again);

    buttonAgain.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (utils.isConnectingToInternet()) {

               categorySubPresenter.getAllListItems(uid, category_id);
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Does anyone know why this button does not work when it is pressed in fragment and how to solve it? Because same code in Activity works without problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When and at where are you make your button visible ?

Comment: Your button visibility is GONE

Comment: visibility is gone

Comment: ahhh, I forgot to remove this from code, it becomes VISIBLE, when in my rxjava call onError appears

Comment: Are you sure that `onClick` is not called? Maybe the problem is here `categorySubPresenter.getAllListItems(uid, category_id);` if the listener is called.

Comment: Iulian Popescu, yes I checked it on debug mode, nothing is called inside of onClick :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is because of the `include` tag. I was warned once that I cannot set listeners in a fragment. So, if you want to set listeners on some button you have to do it within an activity.

There is a fragment callback `onActivityCreated()` that is called when the activity is created, so starting with this moment you can call the Fragment's `getActivity() method`.

Here is an example

```
    @Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    final Activity activity = getActivity();

    activity.findViewById(R.id.toast).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "My toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

}
```